# Android Arraylist Items send in groups

Tags: android, loops, arraylist, items

I want to know, How to send items of arraylist in small groups, Means to say I have 100 items in arraylist and I want to send items in groups, on 1st 4 items send to server, after delay 1 or 2 mins next 4 items send to server and so on to end of items of arraylist.
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can create a Runnable and then use the method postDelayed of the Handler class. 
Everytime the Run method of Runnable is executed, you check if still needs to send more items, if yes, then you use postDelayed again.

```
Handler handler = new Handler();
ArrayList mMyList;

public void sendToServer(ArrayList aList) {

  mMyList = aList;

  handler.post(senderRunnable);

}

int mLastSendIndex = 0;
Runnable senderRunnable = new Runnable(){

@override
void Run() {

// Http call to the sever here, sending 4. 
mLastSendIndex +=4;
if (mLastSendIndex < mMyList.size()) {
    handler.postDelayed(senderRunnable, 4000) // 4 seconds
  } 
 }
}
```

Comment: Hi hmartinezd thanks for quick reply, I am new on Android and programming and I don't know how  write this algo. Can you help me in it?

Comment: Added some sample code, sorry about the mess, but I'm typing from my phone.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could use Timer and TimerTask.

Like this,

```
static int DELAY_TIME = 60000; // ms, 1 min = 60s = 60000s, your delay time
Timer mTimer = new Timer();
TimerTask mTimerTask = new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                // TODO: Your code

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();

            }
        }
    };

    mTimer.schedule(mTimerTask, 0, DELAY_TIME);
}
```